# How to pass information around when working with JavaScript Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

At one point, we are calling our backend several times with `fetch`. Each call returns a promise, which we collect and pass to our `responseHandler`. This handler is supposed to dispatch redux actions when each response comes in. The action will be shaped differently based on two factors:

- the response code of the server
- the content of the request

so we have this

```
function save(objects) {
    let promises = objects.map(object => {
        let promise = fetch(url, {..., body: object});
    });
    responseHandler(promises);
}

function responseHandler(promises) {
    for (let promise of promises) {
        promise
            .then(r => {
                return r.json();
            })
            .then(body => dispatchSomeAction(body));
    }
}
```

So far so good. But now we need info from inside of the `save` and from inside of the anonymous function that receives the `response` object. So I came up with the following approach. But it feels *wrong* to piggyback on the promise object. I can't say why.

```
function save(objects) {
    let promises = objects.map(object => {
        let promise = fetch(url, {..., body: object});
        promise._objectType = object._type;
    });
    responseHandler(promises);
}

function responseHandler(promises) {
    for (let promise of promises) {
        promise
            .then(r => {
                promise._status = r.status;
                return r.json();
            })
            .then(body => dispatchSomeAction({
                status: promise._status,
                type: promise._type, ...body
            }));
    }
}
```

As can be seen, every time I want a value of a scope to be available later, I place it on the promise object because that promise object is in all the other scopes. Is there a *cleaner* way?

Note: The backend returns an object that doesn't hold the `_type` property (actually I clear my objects of those flags before sending them to the backend. It's a frontend flag that I still require when the answer comes)

Comment: Just place your last `then` inside the same scope as your first `then`..

Comment: Please fix all the syntax errors...

Answer (score 1):

You must carry the object. Using ES6 structuring and destructuring is not very clumpsy:

```
function save(objects){
  let promises = objects.map(object => {
    return fetch(url, {..., body: object}).then(r => ({r,type:object._type}));
  }
  responseHandler(promises)
}

function responseHandler(promises){
  for (let promise of promises){
    promise
      .then(({r,type}) => {
        return r.json().then(body => dispatchSomeAction({status: r.status, type, ...body));
      });
  }
}
```

Note that you don't really need to do anything at all with the status, as r it was still in scope where it's used.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like the following

```
function save(objects){
  let promises = objects.map(object) =>{
    return fetch(url, {..., body: object}).then(r=>{
      return {data: r, originalObject: object} 
    })
  }
  responseHandler(promises)
}

function responseHandler(promises){
  for (let promise of promises){
    promise
     .then(r => {
       return {data: r.data.json(), originalObject: r.originalObject)
     .then(r=> dispatchSomeAction({status: r.data.status, type: r.originalObject.type, ...r.data.body));
 }
}
```

you can tweak a little bit, say, without passing the whole object, just the type field.

Comment: Please fix the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to use a single global object (commonly called `state` or `appData` or similar) to store values and allow you to access them from within different closures.

Here's a contrived example of using this pattern to load a bunch of items, and then to reload the data for each item after clicking a "refresh" button:

```
const state = {}

getItemsPromise().then(response => {
  state.items = response.items
})

$(refreshItemsButton).on('click', ()=>{
  state.items.forEach(item => {
    refreshItemPromise(item).then(response => {
      state.items[item.id] == response.item
    })
  })
})
```